# Ruby scraping website using Post request

Tags: ruby, forms, post, get, screen-scraping

I basically am tasked with scraping a website using a post request. I was looking to
"net/http" in ruby and the post examples seem pretty straightforward. The question is if I want to find a store of a chain using zipcode ( chain website uses post to find the store), how can I do it? I have tried couple of stuff but none of them worked.Below is a sample of the code I am using:

```
    url = ARGV[0]
    zipcode = ARGV[1]  

 params = {"q" => "#{zipcode}"}
 result = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("#{url}"),params)
```

I pass url and zipcode as arguments from command line where url is the store locator url of a chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering using Mechanize instead.

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/

Comment: If you need to crawl a site in the future, I would also recommend anemone. Between Mechanize and Anemone, I can extract nearly anything off the web with ruby.